# Backing up Jenkins home directory with a Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, backup, bitbucket, jobs

I have taken a look at several approaches for backing up Jenkins home directory. One of the more intriguing (and seemingly complete), methods for doing so is configuring a Jenkins job which backs up Jenkins home directory to source control.

I am trying to get clear on exactly what will need to be performed (via an  'execute shell' build step), in the backup process. We currently use BitBucket for source control (GIT), and have one Jenkins Master with four Jenkins Agent / Slave build nodes.

**Prerequisites**:

- Initialize Jenkins home directory as a git repo.

**Steps to Backup Jenkins**:

1. CD to Jenkins home directory.
2. Commit all changed files in the Jenkins Home local repository to the
   master branch of the repository.
3. Push the changes from the local repository to the BitBucket
   repository.
4. FIN. A most recent copy of Jenkins home is now stored in source control in the event we need a backup.

So I have several questions for those whom have used this approach before for automated backups of Jenkins:

- Is a backup of Jenkins Home directory alone enough to backup Jenkins
  when a distributed build (agent / slave), system is in place?
- Should any files / directories be excluded in the backup of Jenkins
  Home directory?
- Will initializing Jenkins Home directory as a GIT repository have any
  adverse effects as far as Jenkins is concerned?
- I've noticed some tutorials mention creating a user credential
  Jenkins will use when connecting to BitBucket. How does this work?

Any additional advice is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

On your job you can add BitBucket credentials. But what I did for mine was making the jobs folder a .git repo and I manually commit to it every so often.

You can also make a job to do this for you running a bash script I found online: [Bash Script](https://gist.github.com/cenkalti/5089392)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Setup
#
# - Create a new Jenkins Job
# - Mark "None" for Source Control Management
# - Select the "Build Periodically" build trigger
#   - configure to run as frequently as you like
# - Add a new "Execute Shell" build step
#   - Paste the contents of this file as the command
# - Save
#  
# NOTE: before this job will work, you'll need to manually navigate to the $JENKINS_HOME directory 
# and do the initial set up of the git repository.  
# Make sure the appropriate remote is added and the default remote/branch set up.
#  

# Jenkins Configuraitons Directory
cd $JENKINS_HOME

# Add general configurations, job configurations, and user content
git add -- *.xml jobs/*/*.xml userContent/*

# only add user configurations if they exist
if [ -d users ]; then
    user_configs=`ls users/*/config.xml`

    if [ -n "$user_configs" ]; then
        git add $user_configs
    fi
fi

# mark as deleted anything that's been, well, deleted
to_remove=`git status | grep "deleted" | awk '{print $3}'`

if [ -n "$to_remove" ]; then
    git rm --ignore-unmatch $to_remove
fi

git commit -m "Automated Jenkins commit"

git push -q -u origin master
```